# How to make a textfield display a number with only 2 decimals when unfocused, but show all decimals when focused?

Tags: reactjs, input, material-ui, textfield, number-formatting

I need a field that allows the user to input as many decimals as they want, but once blurred, it will show "X.XX...".

I found a way to truncate the value, but it doesn't display when the input type is 'number'

```
export default function App() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(0.12345);
  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div
      className="App"
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column"
      }}
    >
      <TextField
        label="Raw Number Text Field"
        type="number"
        value={val}
        onChange={(e) => setVal(e.target.value)}
      />
      <TextField
        label="Truncated Number Text Field"
        value={truncateNumber(val)}
        type="number"
      />
      <TextField label="Truncated Text Field" value={truncateNumber(val)} />
      <TextField
        label="Truncated Text Field With Toggle onFocus"
        type="number"
        onFocus={() => {
          setFocused(true);
        }}
        onBlur={() => {
          setFocused(false);
        }}
        value={focused ? val : truncateNumber(val)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
const decimalRegex = new RegExp(`^[+,-]?\\d+(\\.\\d{0,2)?$`);

const truncateNumber = (v) => {
  const value = Number(v);
  const hasTooManuDecimals = !decimalRegex.test(`${value}`);
  if (hasTooManuDecimals && value != null && !isNaN(value)) {
    return value.toFixed(2) + "...";
  }

  return String(value);
};
```

I'm getting "The specified value "0.12..." cannot be parsed, or is out of range"

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-tree-qqy0t?file=/src/App.js:689-1002)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Add a state property of type boolean that is `true` only when focussed, let's call it `truncated`
- have `onFocus` and `onBlur` events on the field that trigger a function, let this function toggle the state
- have value be `this.state.truncated ? this.truncateNumber(value) : value`

Comment: This doesn't solve the "The specified value "0.12..." cannot be parsed, or is out of range" caused by the number type of the field

Comment: Ah sorry. Where do you see that error? I don't see it in your code sandbox.

Comment: I see it in my personal app, not sure why it doesn't appear in codesandbox. But even in the sandbox, the field is empty if the value is a truncated number and the type is number

Comment: If you mean when you use a input of `type="number"`, then yes, you're not allowed to use free formatting such as `...` at the end. What you could do is add `step=".01"` to the field to enforce showing two decimals, and using `:after` in CSS to display the dots like an affix.